# Setting dependencies from global packages in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

Can i set a list of dependecies in `package.json` without installing them with `npm install package --save`locally? If so, leave an examle. Thanks

Comment: Didn't get the question itself. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: For examle i have got express installed with `npm install express -g`. Can i somehow write about it in `package.json`? It's written automatically when you are installing it with `npm install express --save`.

Comment: What do you want to write when its getting written automatically as you said : ). Still not clear : (. Do you mean what ever is installed on your system for which you didn't use --save flag?

Comment: data about dependencies like that:`"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }` Every package that is installed globally and that is used in the current project should be there

Comment: which data are you talking about? Please be a little clear. Are you looking to retrieve the set of dependencies that were earlier installed without a `--save` flag and now you want them to be added in your `package.json`?

Comment: You got the idea. I  am looking to retrieve the set of dependencies that were earlier installed without a `--save` flag and now i want them to be added in my `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right you want to be able to just quickly add the version of express you have installed globally as a dependency to a project.

The only straight forward answer is you shouldn't really be relying on global installs, even for yourself. It sets a bad precedent and may end up with you forgetting to declare dependencies all together.

The closest you can get is just getting a list of your globally installed dependencies and versions (`npm list -g --depth=0`) and installing what you need.

This is two steps, as opposed to just straight up choosing a version of `package` and installing it with the `--save` flag

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your dependencies in package.json manually as below:

```
{
  "name": "my_package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
     "my_dep": "^1.0.0",
     "my_dep_2": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies" : {
    "my_test_framework": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Each dependency is separated with comma and written using the version number.

To install the dependencies

```
npm install
```

You can read the documentation to know more
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning